# Why is a risk neutral measure unique in a discrete time market with continuous states?

Tags: measure-theory, finance

Why is the radon nikodym derivative unique in a discrete time market with continuous states?

By radon nikodym derivative, I meant the derivative with respective to the risk neutral measure and the true risk measure.